# Textbook solutions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, education, textbook-erratum

I am trying to study quantum physics on my own time, and I have been using the textbook "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics," by Bransden and Joachain, as my guide. The book is great and very well written, but for some reason it does not seem to include any answers and solutions to any of the end-of-chapter problems. Worse, despite thorough Internet searching, I have not been able to find any kind of companion site which could contain some of the solutions I need, and all the sites that offer solutions at individual problems are paywalled at prices that I can't afford.

Does anyone know any workarounds in this kind of situation? I love this book and want to keep studying it, but I can't learn much if I have no idea whether my answers to the questions are correct or not.